# Why doesn't a change in X and Y have an effect in w4 and w2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Weird(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
    def getX(self):
        return x 
    def getY(self):
        return y

class Wild(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
    def getX(self):
        return self.x 
    def getY(self):
        return self.y

X = 7
Y = 8

w1 = Weird(X, Y)
w2 = Wild(X, Y)
w3 = Wild(17, 18)
w4 = Wild(X, 18)

X = w4.getX() + w3.getX() + w2.getX()
print(X)
print(w4.getX())

Y = w4.getY() + w3.getY()
Y = Y + w2.getY()
print(Y)

print(w2.getY())
```

I expected:

- `print(w4.getX())` to print out 31.
- `print(Y)` and `print(w2.getY())` to print out 72.

Can someone please explain why aren't the changes in X, Y showing up in w2 or w4 as I expected because to get X and Y out of w2 or w4, we'd need to see the class declaration which would lead us to updated values of X and Y and hence updated instance variables of w2 or w4.

Comment: Why should `w4.x` be affected by a rebinding of the unrelated global variable `X`? Also getters are pretty pointless in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it change w1?

W2 does not contain a reference to Y and W4 does not contain a reference to X. What they have is the value of X and Y when they were constructed.  They store their own variables X and Y.  Changes to one X (either in a W object or outside that object) does not change any of the other separate variables with the same name in a different scope.

Python does not contain pointers, so it is not possible to get the behavior you are looking for with just variable names.

Comment: thank you. i figured this out while asking the question but still needed someone to state this and reassure me.